# How to level up Silver Kenshi to the maximum possible in Mortal Kombat X in Android

Tags: mortal-kombat-x

I used level up cards to level up my silver Kenshi to the max level of 50 however the XP bar below show **140,095/493,000** as shown in the screenshot. No matter what battle I play with Kensi this figure doesn't increase. 
[image]

Does this mean I didn't level up Kenshi to the fullest? or is there any other possibility that I can fill the XP bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens if you use a level up card to reach level 50, it overshoots. 50 is still the max level, so you not getting any more XP is the correct behavior.

Comment: Not getting any more XP makes my Kenshi weaker?

Comment: No, your Kenshi is at the max level, he cant grow any stronger. He is just as strong as any other Kenshi at level 50.

Answer (score 1):

From [this post](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/130102-mortal-kombat-x/71691259), 50 is the max level for cards. [This spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yl79jJhs-62q7NwINjBEsG3k3zRu6b66va5RkS-EdeQ/edit#gid=253788434) shows you the stats for all cards at minimum level (level 1, fusion 0) and at maximum level (level 50, fusion VII).

Comment: Not getting any more XP makes my Kenshi weaker?